# How to only print certain variables from tsv file python

Tags: python

I have a tsv file that contains the following variables with data below each variable. I want to only put the *Drug Name*, *Description* and the *Targeted Virus* into a dictionary. How do I do that?

```
Drug Name   Drugbank ID    Description    Indication    Targeted Virus
```

I have the following code, however it prints all the variables I have into the dictionary. I just want the Drug name, description and the targeted virus

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('flu_results.tsv'),delimiter='\t')

fields = data.next()

for row in data:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))

    print item
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the index of interested columns in fields, then populating the corresponding data with that index from row. Then zip them.